# If string is equal to another string, print something

Tags: c

For some reason this code doesn't output anything, what did I do wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%s",&c);
    if(c=="ab")
    {
        printf("b");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's not how you compare strings in c.

Comment: Strings are compared with the `strcmp` function. Also, `c` is _not_ a string.

Comment: You should allocate memory for your string, either with `char str[64];` or with `malloc()`

Comment: The `strcmp()` returns 0 on equality, it would be `if (strcmp(c, "ab") == 0)`

Comment: Thank you, the transition from Python to C sure is a challenge lol

Comment: @JackLilhammers or, more idiomatically , `if(!strcmp(...))`

Comment: well, they're different beasts, each with its perks and quirks

Comment: Recommend [Introduction to C strings](https://flaviocopes.com/c-strings/).

Comment: @grokestray I transitioned very fast once I got the whiff of C. I don't regret it and enjoy the power of C ! Hope you have fun too, contact me if you have doubts !

Comment: @AnAnt considering the question, I chose the explicit writing

Comment: @JackLilhammers and I wrote like that for along while too, nothing wrong, just leaving it here for the information of the OP

Comment: Also, if you use `strcmp()` for sorting, I think it's better to write `== 0` because you'll have also `< 0` and `> 0`

Comment: Thank you all for the help! @AnAnt Yeah I'm having fun, but it can sometimes get frustrating when I don't know how to do the most basic stuff haha. But hey, it's part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

In C String is not of type character as you have declared (i.e., `char c;`). It's a pointer to a `char`. You need to check for equality as character by character or use standard library function [strcmp](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char c[100];
   scanf("%s", c);
   char *s = "ab";
   if (strcmp(c, s) == 0)
   {
      printf("They are Equal\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: And later, when OP is more knowledgable, maybe he'll transition to `fgets()` :)

Comment: You're reading into an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @interjay Now it should be correct, albeit far from perfect